# find the probability if first event is known

Tags: probability

Emma and Linda toss a coin. Every time tails comes Emma gets a point,
when heads comes, Linda gets one point. The game is won by whoever has three more points than the other first.
Tails comes on the first toss. What is the probability that Emma will win?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use a chart to calculate the probability of winning.

[image: Probability Tree]

Where the black end points are losses and red are wins
the sum of all combinations is 9 and the number of possible ways for her to win is 6; therefore, there is a 2/3's probability of her winning.

This can also be concluded numerically

Since the probability of winning decreases 50% for every turn that is not a winning turn, we cant denote the winning probability as:

$p=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}(1-p)$

$={1\over 2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \Bigl({1\over 4}\Bigr)^{ n}$

$= {1\over2}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}}$

$={1\over 2}\cdot {4\over 3}={2\over 3}$

There is therefore a 2/3 chance of Emma winning

Comment: Please don't answer questions that have provided no effort except a homework dump.